# Fancytree: Cannot unselelct after select mode is changed

Tags: javascript, select, fancytree, unselect

In my application I am switching between selectMode 1 and 3, based on what user has set the options.
When I'm in selectMode 3, I choose some nodes. Then I switch to selectMode 2. If I try to unselect a node now, it will not be unselected and gets filled (see the screenshot) until I **refresh** the page: 
After I refresh the page it work as it should.
[image]

I there is a way to fix this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help to have a jsFiddle or Plunkr to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

You could try to call `tree.render(true, true)` or `tree.reload()`.

If this doesn't work, you can always traverse the tree in selectMode 2 with `tree.visit()` and tweak the `node.selected` and `node.partSel` properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. I will try all of them. And I will try to also to make a jsFiddle or Plunkr sample. Thanks again!